# Integrating this norm

Tags: integration

The norm

\begin{equation}
||u||^{2} = \int_{\mathbb R} 1 \cdot u(x) \cdot \overline{u(x)} dx
\end{equation}

Claim which should be correct

\begin{equation}
||u||^{2} = \int_{\mathbb R} 1 \cdot u(x) \cdot \overline{u(x)} dx \\
= /_{\mathbb R} x u(x) \overline{u(x)} - \int_{\mathbb R} x \left( u(x) \overline{u'(x)} + u'(x) \overline{u(x)} \right) dx
\end{equation}

I think the step is done by the chain rule of integration or its variant product rule in integration by parts by choosing

- $dv = 1 \cdot u(x)$,
- $u = \overline{1 \cdot u(x)}$,
- $v =^{?} x(u(x) \overline{u'(x)} + u'(x) \overline{u(x)}$
- $du = 1$

However, I am uncertain because the selection would imply that

\begin{equation}
v = \int dv \, dx = \int 1 \cdot u(x) \, dx \\
=^{?} x(u(x) u'(x) + u'(x) \overline{u(x)}
\end{equation}

where the last equality does not make sense.

### 2nd Attempt based on Mattos' comments

Choose

- $v = 1$
- $w = \int u \bar{u} dx$
- $v' = 0$
- $w' = u \bar{u}$

Recall $\int w dv = v w - \int v dw$. 
So

\begin{equation}
||u||^{2} = \int 1 \cdot u \bar{u} \, dx \\
= / 1 \cdot u \bar{u} - \int \int 1 \cdot u \bar{u} \, dx \, dx
\end{equation}

where

- missing the prefix $x$ in $\int 1 \cdot u \bar{u} \, dx$
- the minus $\int \int ... dx \, dx$ just does not make sense because I cannot get an expression like $x (u \overline{u'} + u' \bar{u})$.

I think I am doing systematically something wrong. 
It has been a moment while I did manually integration by parts.

---

How can you do integrate right the norm?

Comment: It's done by integration by parts with $v = u \bar u \implies dv = u' \bar u + u \bar u'$, $w' = 1 \implies w = x$

Comment: Yes, but can you get the last equality?

Comment: Integration by parts says

$$\int v w' = vw - \int v'w$$

which is exactly what you have written in your statement if you use the choices I outlined above.

Comment: @Mattos Yes, but how can you get $v$?

Comment: I don't know what you are asking for? _Define_ $v = u \bar u$ in your integration by parts. _Don't_ choose $v = 1 \cdot u$.

Comment: @Mattos That is the problem. If you define $dv = u \bar{u}$, you get $u = 1$ and $du = 0$ which does not lead to the wanted result.

Comment: If you define $dv$ that way, _you end up with your original equation_. Integrating by parts with your method results in

\begin{align}
v &= 1 \quad w = \int u \bar u dx \\
v' &= 0 \quad w' = u \bar u \\
\implies \int 1 \cdot (u \bar u) dx &= 1 \cdot \int u \bar u dx - 0 \\
&= \int u \bar u dx
\end{align}

Comment: @Mattos Yes, your statement is right. Can you apply to the norm and get the wanted result? I cannot at the moment. .

Comment: Sure, I'll write a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$$\lvert \lvert u \rvert \rvert^{2} = \int_{\mathbb{R}} u \bar u dx$$

Using integration by parts which says

$$\int \color{red} v \color{blue} w' = v w - \int v' w \quad (*)$$

Take

\begin{align}
\color{red} v &= u \bar u \implies v' = u' \bar u + u \bar u' \\
\color{blue} w' &= 1 \implies w = x \\
\end{align}

where we applied the product rule to find $v'$. Substituting these into the formula at $(*)$, you get

\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} u \bar u dx &= x u \bar u \bigg\lvert_\mathbb{R} - \int_{\mathbb{R}} x (u' \bar u + u \bar u') dx
\end{align}

as required.